# Why are there always questions with “grandpa”?

Tags: discussion

I always see puzzles with “says grandpa”, “claims grandpa”, e.t.c. Why do we use grandpa?

Comment: Who's "we"? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those questions are almost always written by [a single user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34419/deem). I don't know why they like to make all their questions about "Grandpa", but it's a single person's quirk rather than a tradition on PSE as a whole.

Comment: Would love it if DEEM spots this and provides us with Grandpa's deep and meaningful autobiography... :)

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan I think your comment that I make "all their questions about Grandpa" is incorrect. I have asked over 220 questions total and only 50 to 60 are Grandpa focused.

Comment: I was exaggerating for vividity.

Answer (score 5):

I just saw this. Sorry for the late answer.

What can I say. This is a person very dear to me who is mostly as described. I just felt that introducing a character like Grandpa makes the puzzles interesting and sometimes humorous. His lateral thinking style is now familiar to many and now answers come very quickly.

I have received mostly positive reaction to Grandpa puzzzles and some on the site have come up with their own Grandpa puzzles too.

I certainly like to know if @Culver Kwan has some criticism of these puzzles.